# JMock using mocked objects with concrete a class

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, jmock, cglib

I have an object with no interface (I can't change this), I was able to mock it using

```
Mock mockedClass = mock(ObjectExample.class, "returnObject",
            new Class[ ]{java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer},
            new Object[ ]{1,9001});
```

This object is successfully mocked, and on debugging I can see the parameters are being successfully set, my question is how can I then use this mocked object; for example how would I return the object `returnOnject` to use later on in the code, and to mock out calls to this object?

*Edit:* I am using JMock with CGLIB

Comment: where is this object to be used? Can you show us the test?

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would not use jMock outside a unit test but use a proxy framework such as cglib or javassist directly. You can create a proxy of `ObjectExample` which basically represents a subclass of this *mocked* class. You can then use this subclass object by the type of `ObjectExample`.

Here is an example of how you can create a proxy with cglib:

```
@Test
public void testMethodInterceptor() throws Exception {
  Enhancer enhancer = new Enhancer();
  enhancer.setSuperclass(ObjectExample.class);
  enhancer.setCallback(new MethodInterceptor() {
    @Override
    public Object intercept(Object obj, Method method, Object[] args, MethodProxy proxy)
        throws Throwable {
      if(method.getName().equals("returnObject")) {
        // Add your proxy logic here.
      } else {
        proxy.invokeSuper(obj, args);
      }
    }
  });
  ObjectExample proxy = (ObjectExample) enhancer.create();
}
```